# Performant Approach to Count Shared Between Azure Functions

Tags: c#, azure, locking, azure-functions, mutual-exclusion

Objects are moving through a pipeline of Azure Functions. I'd like to maintain a count of objects in the pipeline by having the first Azure Function increment a shared counter when they enter and the last Azure Function decrement it when they exit. Via dependency injection, the Azure Functions do have access to a shared object that could host this counter. I know that I need to use a locking mechanism to prevent the Functions from overwriting the counter with stale values, but what's the best method to use with minimal impact to performance?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Redis Cache is the best  and recommended way to cache data between Azure functions - In this way the cached value is shared between all instances, and doesn't rely on the Azure functions runtime reusing the same machine for all function calls.

Although if you want to share recollection between two different functions in the same function app and you don't want to use Azure redis cache then , i  would suggest you to use memory cache as it is thread safe.

here is something which you can write it in both your function:

```
static MemoryCache memCacheObject = MemoryCache.Default;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    var cacheObj = memCacheObject["cachedCount"];
    var cachedCount = (cacheObj == null) ? 0 : (int)cacheObj;   
    memCacheObject.Set("cachedCount", ++cachedCount, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddMinutes(5));

    log.Info($"Webhook triggered memory count {cachedCount}");
    return ...
}
```

Please note that both you function needs to be in the same function app.

You can read below article for sharing state between Azure function.

```
**https://markheath.net/post/sharing-state-between-azure-functions**
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I agree with Redis Cache but highly doubt in memory solution will work if function app scales or shut down. Function app can scales to multiple VMs and in memory wouldn't work.